# Response.Redirect using ~ Path

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

I have a method that where I want to redirect the user back to a login page located at the root of my web application.

I'm using the following code:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?ReturnPath=" + Request.Url.ToString());
```

This doesn't work though.  My assumption was that ASP.NET would automatically resolve the URL into the correct path.  Normally, I would just use

```
Response.Redirect("../Login.aspx?ReturnPath=" + Request.Url.ToString());
```

but this code is on a master page, and can be executed from any folder level.  How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

> I think you need to drop the "~/" and replace it with just "/", I believe / is the root

**STOP RIGHT THERE!** :-) unless you want to hardcode your web app so that it can only be installed at the root of a web site.

"~/" ***is*** the correct thing to use, but the reason that your original code didn't work as expected is that `ResolveUrl` (which is used internally by `Redirect`) tries to first work out if the path you are passing it is an absolute URL (e.g. "**http://server/**foo/bar.htm" as opposed to "foo/bar.htm") - but unfortunately it does this by simply looking for a colon character ':' in the URL you give it. But in this case it finds a colon in the URL you give in the `ReturnPath` query string value, which fools it - therefore your '~/' doesn't get resolved.

The fix is that you should be URL-encoding the `ReturnPath` value which escapes the problematic ':' along with any other special characters.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?ReturnPath=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString()));
```

Additionally, I recommend that you (or anyone) never use `Uri.ToString` - because it gives a human-readable, more "friendly" version of the URL - not a necessarily correct one (it unescapes things). Instead use Uri.AbsoluteUri - like so:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?ReturnPath=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve the URL first
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx);
and add the parameters after it got resolved.

Answer (score -3):

What about using

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("http://{0}/Login.aspx?ReturnPath={1}", Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"], Request.Url.ToString()));
```

Comment: Using the server name is problematic as it's likely the site could use a custom DNS. Having the protocol hardcoded as "http" would also cause issues for sites using https.

Comment: I find it a legit alternative if someone would like to do it in this form