# Problem redirecting to another page

Tags: c#, redirect, response

I am getting "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error while trying to redirect ot another page.

```
string targetURL = "~/AnotherForm.aspx?Xresult=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(res);
    Response.Redirect(targetURL);
```

Thanks
BB

Comment: Please include more info. Where is this redirect taking place? What is happening on the page it's redirected to? Is it just in IE that this error occurs? Is it a compiler error or a runtime error?

Comment: I have an website app called Claims and I am trying to redirect from Default.aspx to AnotherForm.aspx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ResolveURL()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) which is used by `Response.Redirect()`, doesn't work nicely with UrlEncode, try this:

```
string targetURL = "~/AnotherForm.aspx?Xresult=" +  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(res);
```

Also check this related SO answer: [Response.Redirect using ~ Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221/response-redirect-using-path/31437#31437)

Answer (score 3):

You're miscalling `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`.

You should only `Encode` the parameter value.
By `Encode`ing the entire URL, you are escaping the `/` characters, messing up your URL.