# Tilde showing in URL instead of mapping to root

Tags: .net, asp.net, tilde

We have a old .net site that runs on the 2.0 framework. In this site there are multiple calls that redirect when needed by calling response.redirect(). For some reason that I cannot figure out the ` character has stopped being mapped to the root - and is actualy showing as part of the path. For example:

```
Response.Redirect("~/shopping/checkout_confirm.aspx?rc=" & 
    MyPayment.ResponseCode & "&rt=" & MyPayment.ResponseText)
```

Now ends up trying to redirect to:

`https://www.site.com/shopping/~/shopping/checkout_confirm.aspx?rc=3`

I have tried the following aswell, with no luck:

```
Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveUrl("~/shopping/checkout_confirm.aspx?rc=" &
    MyPayment.ResponseCode & "&rt=" & MyPayment.ResponseText))
```

When run in the dev environment the url maps correctly... Any idea's on what could be the cause / fix for this problem?

Comment: What is in your MyPayment.ResponseText? It may be that the value of that is messing things up. You may need to URLEncode it.

Comment: Is shopping a directory in your site or is it a virtual directory in IIS (an application)? Also what is the result of your `Page.ResolveUrl` call?

Comment: check this thread, I hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221/response-redirect-using-path

Comment: patmortech had it right. Once I encoded the response it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the ResponseText contained a character that needed to be encoded.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a relative path instead:

```
Response.Redirect("checkout_confirm.aspx?rc=" & MyPayment.ResponseCode & "&rt=" & MyPayment.ResponseText)
```

Comment: That would work for the example - but fails to map from the root of the site. It would not work in all uses of redirect.